# Recommendations for reading "Algebraic Topology" by Allen Hatcher

Tags: at.algebraic-topology

I really want to start reading "Algebraic Topology," and I have the prerequisites for doing so. But I wanted to know if anyone might have any advice for someone that wants to learn most efficiently/effectively when reading this book.

Comment: How much time do you have?  The exercises in that book are fantastic, but if you try to learn everything it may drive you mad.... Good luck!

Comment: I'm not certain there is much non-tautological advice to be given.   To learn efficiently you have to give generous amounts of energy to productive pursuits. . .